# Show the Complete Date of Selected Month and Year in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I wanted to select the Month and Year only BUT I wanted to output the first day of the selected month and year and the last day of the selected month and year. Output dates should be complete.
They are `fromDate` and `toDate`.

For example: if Jan 2021 is chosen then

fromDate is `01-01-2021`

toDate is `31-01-2021`

Pls check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-select-dropdown-month-year-wkrd4?file=/src/index.js)

You can modify the `months` and `years` array since they are static. Modify in the best way possible.

```
  <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "1em", flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <h3> Month </h3>
    <Select onChange={(e) => select(e)}>
      {months.map((key, index) => (
        <option value={key} key={index}>
          {key}
        </option>
      ))}
    </Select>
    <h3> Year </h3>
    <Select onChange={(e) => select(e)}>
      {years.map((key, index) => (
        <option value={key} key={index}>
          {key}
        </option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </div>
```

Comment: date-fns has a nice `lastDayOfMonth` function that might make this easier. https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/lastDayOfMonth

Comment: @ChrisFarmer. That be great but I prefer not to :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have one selected date, fashioned from the combination of your two dropdowns.  Instead of storing multiple pieces of info (both month and year), consider storing a single date created from those fields.

```
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date());

  const handleMonthSelect = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const month = parseInt(value, 10);
    setSelectedDate(new Date(getYear(selectedDate), month));
  };

  const handleYearSelect = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const year = parseInt(value, 10);
    setSelectedDate(new Date(year, getMonth(selectedDate)));
  };
```

Then you can display that info with some calculated values from your date in the state. Here I use date-fns, but you could have your own lookup or calculation somewhere to find the last day of the month.

```
<div>First: {startOfMonth(selectedDate).toDateString()}</div>
<div>Last: {lastDayOfMonth(selectedDate).toDateString()}</div>
```

To deal with the dynamic list of years, I created a custom hook that serves up the list of years:

```
export const useDynamicYears = ({ startingYear, numberOfYears }) => {
  const [years, setYears] = React.useState(() => {
    const dynamicYears = [];
    for (let year = startingYear; year < startingYear + numberOfYears; year++) {
      dynamicYears.push(year);
    }
    return dynamicYears;
  });
  return years;
};

// and to use it...
const dynamicYears = useDynamicYears({
  startingYear: 2015,
  numberOfYears: 20
});
```

Here's a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-select-dropdown-month-year-forked-wcr6u

Comment: Thanks Chris. Do you have any idea how we can make the years.js better? cause we have to manually write several years.

Comment: by the way I want to output something like this as stated in my question. fromDate is `01-01-2021`

toDate is `31-01-2021`. Thank you

Comment: The year thing sounds like a `for` loop to me.  And the second is just date formatting, isn't it?

Comment: Because that seems like an easy problem for a google search and I didn't think you were asking that.

Comment: The first problem is Im asking for advice since we were going to write several years in years.js? How can we make it dynamic without api of course?

Comment: I feel like you might be making the year problem harder than it needs to be.  I modified the sandbox to use a dynamic list of years.

Comment: Thanks Chris for all your help

Comment: Please also add previous years. Thank you